# How to change title position for a NVD3.js graph

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

I am using SealReport which uses NVD3 to render charts. One example is as the link: http://demo.sealreport.org/InitExecuteReport?path=%5cDashboard+-+Sales.srex

How can I put the title at the top of the chart? Thanks!

[image]